# iPhone renders italic tag (<i></i>) tiny

Tags: ios, css, iphone, webkit, rendering

We found an issue with iPhone's rendering of the italic tag. When a `font-family` is defined for it that differs from its parent's `font-family`, the italic text renders much smaller than it should. The issue does not appear to occur on all iOS devices, just the iPhone (at least versions 4 - 6).

Test: http://www.eyesforward.com/etc/italic-fail.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-family: serif;
    }
    i {
      font-family: Arial;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      "The freaking thing <i>works</i>," Strong said with amazement, punctuating this key verb with his hands like an orchestra conductor giving a downbeat. "It's beautiful. It does exactly what we wanted it to do."
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arh20.png

Comment: When you use different font families, like serif vs. Arial here, you should *expect* differences in glyph sizes, even when the font size is the same. Normally Arial glyphs are *larger* than typical serif font glyphs. I wonder if iPhone tries to compensate for this by automatically using smaller font size. In any case, on typographic grounds, font families should not be mixed within paragraphs of text, or at least you should select *matching* fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the font size for the body and italic elements to see if it fixes the issue:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-family: serif;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    i {
      font-family: Arial;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
</style>
```

Then try just setting it for the body and see if the issue is still there. Every browser has it's own style rules it applies to various elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }
</style>
```